# Using __aiter__ and __anext__ in a collections.abc.Coroutine Subclass to add functionality by manually awaiting a coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am working on a project to run File I/O in a separate thread, however I wanted to make an improvement to my open() coroutine. Before adding the `@helper`, in order to use the functionality of the _Filer class, it was necessary to do the following:

```
async with await open('myfile'): #works fine, just not preferred
  ...
async for i in await open('file.txt'): #also works fine
  ...
```

The whole point of the `AddFunctionality` class and the `helper` decorator is to `await` the coroutine for the user, so they can use it like so:

```
async with open('file.txt'): #this works
   ...
async for i in open('file.txt'): #this is completely broken
   ...
```

Fortunately, **everything except for `__aiter__` and `__anext__` (the components of an `async for` statement) are working perfectly**. I am just not sure how I can await `self._coro` in the context of `__aiter__` and `__anext__`. Any help is appreciated.

````
from collections.abc import Coroutine
from functools import wraps


class AddFunctionality(Coroutine):
    __slots__ = ("_coro", "_obj")

    def __init__(self, coro):
        self._coro = coro
        self._obj = None
        print('calling init')
    def send(self, value):
        print('calling send')
        return self._coro.send(value)

    def throw(self, typ, val=None, tb=None):
        print('calling throw')
        if val is None:
            return self._coro.throw(typ)

        if tb is None:
            return self._coro.throw(typ, val)

        return self._coro.throw(typ, val, tb)

    def close(self):
        print('calling close')
        return self._coro.close()

    def __await__(self):
        print('calling await')
        return self._coro.__await__()

    async def __aenter__(self):
        print('calling aenter')
        self._obj = await self._coro
        return self._obj

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        print('calling aeixt')
        await self._obj.close()
        self._obj = None
    def __aiter__(self):
        return self #
    async def __anext__(self):
        await self._coro # I have no idea what I'm doing 
        #error: RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine

def helper(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> AddFunctionality:
        return AddFunctionality(method(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

@helper
async def open(*args, **kwargs):
    f =  _Filer(*args, **kwargs)
    #keep in mind that the `_Filer` class has __aiter__, __anext__, __aenter__, and __aexit__ attributes
    await f.returner() #this just opens the file up. it's not relevant to my question
    return f```
````

Comment: Why can't your just return `self._coro.__aiter__()` from your `__aiter__` function, and do `await self._coro.__anext__()` in your `__anext__` function?

Comment: As you suspect, the part where you have "no idea what you're doing" is indeed incorrect. You cannot await the same coroutine instance more than once. `async for` works by calling (and awaiting) `aiter.__anext__` in each iteration. In other words, your `__aiter__` should call `coro.__aiter__` before returning self, and store the result in (say) `self._coro_iter`. Then your `__anext__` can just `return await self._coro_iter.__anext__()`. (Note the `return`, without it your `__anext__` would just keep returning None.)

Comment: @PaulCornelius Returning `self._coro.__aiter__()` from `__aiter__` would be wrong because then `AddFunctionality.__anext__` would never get called. Maybe that's ok if the OP just wants to combine iteration and context management, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @user4815162342 Question for you:  `__aiter__` must return an asynchronous iterator but that doesn't have to be `self.`  Client code later calls `a.__anext__()`, where a is the object returned by `__aiter__`.  In that case, no `__anext__` is needed. The OP's requirements are indeed fuzzy here as you point out.  Your solution seems better, however, since it also handles the case where `coro.__aiter__()` does not return the coro object itself but some other object.  Also, `__anext__` is supposed to return an awaitable object, so shouldn't your (any my) return expression not contain the "await'?

Comment: @PaulCornelius *In that case, no `__anext__` is needed.* Correct, and that's what I meant by "maybe that's ok" - if the OP doesn't want to intercept `__anext__` , then maybe they don't need it because `AddFunctionality.__aiter__` will return the underlying async iterator directly, and _that_ object will have an `__anext__`.

Comment: @PaulCornelius *shouldn't return expression not contain the "await'?* If `__anext__` is defined as `async def`, then it must `return await bla.__anext__()`. If it's defined as `def`, then it can get away with `return bla.__anext__()`. The two mostly equivalent, the only difference being in the timing of execution of the surrounding code. Say if you do `x = a.__anext__(); <something>; await x`, *and* `a.__anext__` does something before delegating to `bla.__anext__()`, then defining `a.__anext__` as sync or async will differ in whether that code is invoked before or after `<something>`.

Comment: @user4815162342.  Makes sense, thanks.  It's interesting that when you write `async for a in b:` the a's are not awaitable objects, but simple objects that are results of `await b.__aiter()__`.  I've actually used `await for` successfully in my own code without thinking too much about what was really going on.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Yes, though you probably meant `__anext__` rather than `__aiter__`? But yes, the idea is to get completely normal objects (such as strings or websocket messages) in the end, and the whole awaiting thing to be a mere implementation detail that keeps the event loop functioning.

Comment: Hi, thank you both for your input. I will have to do some testing and tweaking, but you have both explained this very well, and I feel much more educated on the topic of asynchronous iteration.